# Prevent AWS IAM admin user to change policies assigned by another admin user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Not sure if this can be implemented, but is there anyway to prevent IAM admin user from changing the IAM policies to him/ her by other admin user?

Eg: - Admin 1 assigns admin policy to Admin 2 with some restrictions
Now, admin 2 can do whatever they want apart from removing policies assigned by admin 1 or adding any extra IAM policies to themself. They can change policies for any other resource or user (but not admin 1).

So far have implemented,

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestedRegion": [
                        "region1",
                        "region2"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1675697205087",
            "Action": [
                "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
                "iam:DeletePolicy",
                "iam:DeleteRole",
                "iam:DeleteRolePolicy",
                "iam:DetachRolePolicy",
                "iam:PutRolePolicy"
            ],
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::acc_no:user/admin2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Even after this, admin2 can attach other IAM policies to itself & make changes to even admin1 user

Comment: I think you're confusing what Resource relates to for these IAM actions. For example, per the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_awsidentityandaccessmanagement.html), the resource associated with `iam:AttachRolePolicy` is an IAM role, not an IAM user.

Comment: Jarmond, I think what you are saying is correct. I may need to change it to attachuserpolicy & try out.

Comment: @jarmod We tried to make changes as per the doc. Now aloong with Role, we also added deny permission for users & permission boundries too, Thanks for sharing the doc & pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

> but is there anyway to prevent IAM admin user from changing the IAM policies to him/ her by other admin user?

Yes, this is what [permission boundaries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html) are for.

> Admin 1 assigns admin policy to Admin 2 with some restrictions Now, admin 2 can do whatever they want apart from removing policies assigned by admin 1 or adding any extra IAM policies to themself. They can change policies for any other resource or user (but not admin 1)

Your policy looks fine, but make sure it is enforced as a permission boundary by `Admin 1` for `Admin2`, e.g.:

```
{
    "Action": [
        "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
        "iam:DeletePolicy",
        "iam:DeleteRole",
        "iam:DeleteRolePolicy",
        "iam:DetachRolePolicy",
        "iam:PutRolePolicy"
    ],
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::acc_no:user/admin1"
}
```

Comment: Will try out permission boundaries. It's one area in IAM that we have not explored yet.
Hopefully it will resolve our issue

Comment: For some reason when adding the deny action as permission boundary policy, it blocked other services apart from IAM. We had to modify the above policy to make it more restrictive & work properly. 

But your idea is something definitely worth more looking into.

Comment: @CloudWanderer *it blocked other services apart from IAM* like what?