# How can I restrict AWS IAM role to be only assumed by EMR and not any user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to restrict access to certain data to AWS EMR only. Basically restricting access to data only to the scheduled (EMR) jobs and no other user can use other resources (lambda, sagemaker) to read the data.

Also, how can I restrict changes to the IAM policy attached to the IAM role so that the Admin doesn't change the policy once it's created?

Realy appreciate any inputs!

Answer (score 0):

When you create an IAM role, you create two policies: A role trust policy that specifies who can assume the role and a permissions policy that specifies what can be done with the role. You specify the trusted principal who is allowed to assume the role in the role trust policy.

### 1. Custom trust policy

For example, the following trust policy includes the `aws:SourceArn` and `aws:SourceAccount` global condition keys, which limit the permissions that you give Amazon EMR to particular resources in your account.

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "elasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceAccount": "<account-id>"
                },
                "ArnLike": {
                    "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:elasticmapreduce:<region>:<account-id>:*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the place where you can define trust policy.

[image]

### 2. Restrict changes to the IAM policy

> How can I restrict changes to the IAM policy attached to the IAM role so that the Admin doesn't change the policy once it's created?

Use [Permissions boundaries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html) on the IAM Role while creating it.

Refer this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76047985/1273882